# Можно ли построить маршрут с учетом грузоподъемности автомобиля?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли построить маршрут с учетом грузоподъемности автомобиля?
Ведь грузовому автотранспорту далеко не везде разрешен проезд.

Comment: А какая задача решается, расчёт доставки для сайта? В веб-версии Яндекс.Карт при составлении маршрута сейчас можно указать параметры грузовика, в API такого функционала пока нет.

Comment: В 1С для планирования маршрута нашего транспорта нужно построить его в Яндекс.Картах. При этом маршрут должен строиться с учетом того, что перевозятся опасные грузы.

Comment: Тогда стоит обратить внимание на [этот сервис](https://yandex.ru/routing/). Есть [готовая обработка для 1C](https://yandex.ru/routing/doc/vrp/concepts/1c-integration-modules_index-page.html)

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Будем пробовать.